# for loop using parallel computing

Tags: python, numpy

```
    sens = 0.7
    [num_y, num_x] = np.where((p < c*sens) | (p > c*sens))
    #[num_y, num_x] = np.where((corrected_w < c*0.97) | (corrected_w > c*1.03))

    ar = np.zeros((3,3))
    ar2 = np.zeros((3,3))
    for n in range(num_y.shape[0]):
        for j in range(-1,2):
            for k in range(-1,2):
                if num_y[n]+j == -1 or num_x[n]+k == -1 or num_y[n]+j == 576 or num_x[n]+k == 576:
                    ar[j+1][k+1] = 0
                    ar2[j+1][k+1] = 0
                else:
                    ar[j+1][k+1] = corrected_w[num_y[n]+j][num_x[n]+k]
                    ar2[j+1][k+1] = corrected_org_I[num_y[n]+j][num_x[n]+k]
        ar[1][1] = 0
        ar2[1][1] = 0
        corrected_w[num_y[n]][num_x[n]] = np.sum(ar)/np.count_nonzero(ar)
        corrected_org_I[num_y[n]][num_x[n]] = np.sum(ar2)/np.count_nonzero(ar2)
```

I want to compute `for n in range(num_y.shape[0]):` using parallel.

Because n is almost 100000 steps, so execution speed is slow a lot.

Please help me.

Comment: It looks like something that maybe could be broadcasted (which would be much faster without using multiprocessing), but that code is . . . something.  What exactly are you trying to do?  It seems like an iterative process, which even multiprocessing won't help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "using parallel". But to speed up your execution you can use multi processing. 
Number of processes and its performance depends on the resource provided. Let's suppose you can afford 4 processes to be running in parallel.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
for n in range(num_y.shape[0]):
    pool.apply_async(\\call you function to do the operations.\\)
```

You can also implement code for waiting till the process has finished execution before exiting.

You can refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html for detailed usage.